# How to know from which yum repository a package has been installed?

Tags: linux, yum, package-management, repository

After I have installed a package by yum (with multiple repositories configured), how can I find from which repository it has been installed?

If I run `yum info package-name` (or `yum list package-name`), I can only see that the package is "installed".

Comment: Great question!  I installed yum-utils and tried one it's utils called repoquery, but no luck.

Comment: see also http://serverfault.com/questions/90409/how-can-i-verify-which-repository-a-package-resides-on-in-centos :)

Comment: @warren your link is not useful because your link is a question about "what repo is an rpm stored in" but this question asks "what repo is an INSTALLED rpm from". different questions.

Comment: if you are used to doing `rpm -qa|grep NAME` then you can [do `yum list installed|grep NAME` to find what repo the rpm is from](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22560/list-all-rpm-packages-installed-from-repo-x).

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith - 7 years ago, it was close. Today, it's ***still*** similar. Never said it was the **same**. Just that it was related.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

With `yum-utils` installed, `repoquery` will provide the information you seek (here 'epel' being the repository).

```
$ repoquery -i cherokee

Name        : cherokee
Version     : 0.99.49
Release     : 1.el5
Architecture: i386
Size        : 8495964
Packager    : Fedora Project
Group       : Applications/Internet
URL         : http://www.cherokee-project.com/
Repository  : epel
Summary     : Flexible and Fast Webserver
Description :
Cherokee is a very fast, flexible and easy to configure Web Server. It supports
the widespread technologies nowadays: FastCGI, SCGI, PHP, CGI, TLS and SSL
encrypted connections, Virtual hosts, Authentication, on the fly encoding,
Apache compatible log files, and much more.
```

Comment: repoquery does not seem to work right, i get different package versions then `yum info package_name`, it does not seem to query the repositories in the same order as yum.

Comment: Same here on a few servers. `yum info package_name` returns more results than repoquery apparently. This is why stack exchange should not lock in votes.

Comment: I found Xiong Chiamiov's answer not correct. `repoquery -i $pkg` gives repo from which a `$pkg` is available, not the repo from which the `$pkg` was installed. I did that command and `rpm -qi $pkg` and got different version numbers. `rpm` resulted in an earlier version number than that of `repoquery`.

Comment: It's possible your local copy is out-of-date, or it was installed with additional commands to yum (e.g. `--use-mirror`).  I don't think it's possible to *always* get the right answer.

Comment: user158844 is right. This will tell you what repos provide a given package, but not what repo a specific package came from. If you installed a package from a certain repo, removed that repo, then installed another repo that provides a package with the same name, running 'repoquery -i' like this would return to you packages listing the newly installed repo, *not* the one that you actually installed the package from. The asker wants to know what package the installed software actually came from. Not what current repos happen to have packages with the same name.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, as stated above it shows from where a package is available, not where it was installed from as asked.

Answer (score 57):

What version of yum?

On the current version if the installed package is the same version as the most recent one available then the repo it was installed from is shown.

```
$ yum info irssi
Installed Packages
Name       : irssi
Arch       : i586
Version    : 0.8.14
Release    : 1.fc11
Size       : 2.3 M
Repo       : installed
From repo  : updates
Summary    : Modular text mode IRC client with Perl scripting
URL        : http://irssi.org/
License    : GPLv2+
Description: Irssi is a modular IRC client with Perl scripting. Only text-mode
           : frontend is currently supported. The GTK/GNOME frontend is no
           : longer being maintained.

$ yum --version
3.2.23
```

If there is a newer package available, then it will be shown separately, with the new version showing the repo it's available from.

Comment: I'm using yum 3.2.19 on CentOs 5.3 and "From repo" row doesn't exist.

Comment: Yep...I was testing it on 3.2.21, which doesn't have that info anywhere.  When I did it on my box that has 3.2.23, it worked.

Comment: Now this is the best solution, but not applicable for RHEL/Centos 5.3. 
I accept this solution, but I ready to choose another answer if will be applicable also for RHEL/Centos 5.3.

Comment: This is a no-go in CentOS 5.5 either.

Comment: "From rep" is not available even in centos 5.8

Comment: the yum command will just show "Repo : installed" which means nothing

Comment: From an answer below, when passed the -v (verbose) flag, yum info has "From repo: " entry.

Answer (score 26):

Coming way to late but (at least on Fedora 15) one can use yumdb for similar queries:

```
yumdb info 'python*'
```

And what I actually needed to list packages from given repo(s):

```
yumdb search from_repo 'my-*-repo'
```

Comment: It works also on Fedora 14

Comment: works on RHEL 6.2

Answer (score 15):

If all else fails, you can inspect the yumdb manually. It's located in `/var/lib/yum/yumdb` and contains detailed information on every installed package. You'll be particularly interested in `from_repo`. For example, for the `bind-utils` package:

```
# for i in /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/*bind-utils*/*; do echo $i: `cat $i`; done
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/73ea08770fa666e18c59842bf65fa0f3a0b103d8-bind-utils-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1-x86_64/checksum_data: 39f7840f93d3d76825a9e8da79cfe0366f7fad68f018a273477aee62cccfa3f4
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/73ea08770fa666e18c59842bf65fa0f3a0b103d8-bind-utils-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1-x86_64/checksum_type: sha256
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/73ea08770fa666e18c59842bf65fa0f3a0b103d8-bind-utils-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1-x86_64/command_line: install bind-utils
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/73ea08770fa666e18c59842bf65fa0f3a0b103d8-bind-utils-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1-x86_64/from_repo: updates
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/73ea08770fa666e18c59842bf65fa0f3a0b103d8-bind-utils-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1-x86_64/from_repo_revision: 1397654451
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/73ea08770fa666e18c59842bf65fa0f3a0b103d8-bind-utils-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1-x86_64/from_repo_timestamp: 1397654759
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/73ea08770fa666e18c59842bf65fa0f3a0b103d8-bind-utils-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1-x86_64/installed_by: 0
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/73ea08770fa666e18c59842bf65fa0f3a0b103d8-bind-utils-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1-x86_64/reason: user
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/73ea08770fa666e18c59842bf65fa0f3a0b103d8-bind-utils-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1-x86_64/releasever: 6
```

To get just the information you want:

```
# cat /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/*bind-utils*/from_repo
updates
```

Later versions will provide even more data; for instance in EL 7 the exact mirror and URL from which the package was downloaded is stored here.

Comment: +1. But it's even better to do something like: `for i in /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/*bind-utils*/*; do echo $i: \`cat $i\` | grep -oP 'from_repo:\ \K.*'; done`, which in the above example returns: `updates` - much more readable!

Comment: @GregDubicki The point of the command was to show more of the context of what is going on and how things are stored. It apparently failed to do so: There is no need to `grep` anything here, and you can even drop the loop. A very simple `cat /var/lib/yum/yumdb/b/*bind-utils*/from_repo` is all you need.

Comment: This is what I needed.  I wanted to know whether an installed package was installed from a repo or a local package file, and this tells me that information.  Thanks!

Comment: Great answer! I used this to establish a unique list of what all repos were in use on a given server via:

# for file in $(find /var/lib/yum/yumdb -name "from_repo" -print); do (cat "${file}"; echo); done | sort -u

Answer (score 7):

To see what installed from repo epel: (Should work under Centos 5.5) note, if you have no repo named epel, it will spit out everything installed.

```sh
repoquery --repoid=epel -a | xargs yum list installed
```

Comment: This appears to work as long as there isn't an updated package in the repository. So you need to run yum update just before using it.

Answer (score 6):

```
rpm -qi packagename
```

Will tell you the vendor and packager

Answer (score 5):

The simplest and most straightforward approach without installing any extra tools, greping or outputting extraneous information is simply:

```
yum list installed [package name]
```

The third column will provide the ID of the repository the package was installed from.

This was mentioned in a comment on the original question using grep, but that's not necessary. You can just pass the package name directly to `yum` to filter.

Comment: Caveat! If you're trying to do this in a script (or even `|` it to `less` or `grep`), the lines will get oddly wrapped because it assumes a default screen width. You need to do a bit of magic to get the "expected" formatting of one package per line (via [Allen Kistler](http://fedora.12.x6.nabble.com/yum-list-display-some-package-in-2-rows-tp2496921p2496962.html) via [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=584525#c9)) - `yum list installed | tr "\n" "#" | sed -e 's/# / /g' | tr "#" "\n"`

Answer (score 4):

If the package was installed recently, you can look in /var/cache/yum.

Within that directory, there is a directory for each repo, and in that a packages directory.  So, you would do something like:

```
find /var/cache/yum -name [package-name]*
```

However, cache has to be enabled in your /etc/yum.conf file:

```
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
keepcache=1
```

Note that a `yum clean [packages|all]` will clear out the cache directory.

If the cache directory is empty, there is an alternative way.  The information that is read by `yum info [package]` comes from /var/cache/yum/[repo]/primary.xml.gz

You can look through the file by entering:

```
gunzip -d -c /var/cache/yum/[repo]/primary.xml.gz | grep '<name>[package]'
```

However, on machines where `yum info [package]` does not display "From repo : ", as indicated by 'theotherreceive', it is because it is not in the file primary.xml, so there will be no way to retrieve that information.  Therefore, if the package is in two or more primary.xml files, you will have to determine the repo priority on you system.

Comment: This solution maybe an option (I vote it), but I am looking for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 4):

Based on and answer by [Swoogan](https://serverfault.com/users/10801/swoogan)
On RedHat and CentOS one can do

```
sudo grep -ir PACKAGE_NAME /var/cache/yum/
```

The results should look something like

```
Binary file /var/cache/yum/REPOSITORY_NAME/primary.xml.gz.sqlite matches
```

Where *repository_name*  is the repository where your package can be found, and it was probably installed from the first one in a list (see yum repolist)

Answer (score 2):

So I know this is a somewhat old question - but it comes up on the google search for what I was looking for.

There is also a method to get a unique list of repos used:

```
# repoquery -ai | grep 'Repository  : ' | sort | uniq
```

This will list the repositories that have had packages installed from.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above commands worked for me. This is what I had to do.

```
yum provides "*compat-libstdc*"
```

A good reference is here.

https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/rh_yum_cheatsheet_1214_jcs_print-1.pdf

Comment: NOTE: `provides` subcommand is supported also by `dnf`.

Answer (score 1):

Is that information captured anywhere?  The package doesn't have that information, and yum doesn't care after it finds the package.  You could probably piece it together by figuring out what repos have the package and then determine which one has priority.

Comment: This solution maybe an option (I vote it), but only for recent installed package, because I can change the repository and their priority.

Answer (score 1):

Not a great solution, but I found that yum list available will show you where the most up to date version of each package is available, e.g.:

yum list available | grep gstreamer

```
PackageKit-gstreamer-plugin.x86_64 0.3.16-1.fc10          updates
```

bluez-gstreamer.i386               4.30-2.fc10            updates
gstreamer.i386                     0.10.21-2.fc10         fedora
gstreamer-devel.i386               0.10.21-2.fc10         fedora
gstreamer-devel.x86_64             0.10.21-2.fc10         fedora
gstreamer-plugins-bad-devel.i386   0.10.9-1.fc10          rpmfusion-free
gstreamer-plugins-bad-devel.x86_64 0.10.9-1.fc10          rpmfusion-free

So you could do a yum list available on your package, then compare your installed version using yum list installed, and have a good idea of which repo it came from if the versions match.

Comment: This is true only is the package is not yet installed.

Comment: While it doesn't answer the OPs question exactly, it was very helpful for me because it works in Centoss 5.5 with just yum and  no other utils, and you can: 1. Uninstall the package then query to see where the repo is then reinstall, or 2.  Query on a different machine without the package installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the verbose flag to "yum info":

```
yum info -v <package_name>
```

The installation repository will be under the "From repo" output.

Comment: This seems to be the only solution that does not require installing yum-utils.

Comment: This only lists "installed" for me.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is this:

```
rpm -qa --qf '%{NAME} %{VENDOR}\n'
```

More tips and tricks are available here: http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/YumAndRPM

Comment: In this way (adding a pipe whith grep -i package name) I discover the vendor, but not the repository.

Comment: The vendor has (almost) nothing to do with the repository.