# How can I verify which repository a package resides on in Centos?

Tags: linux, centos, yum, packages

I'd like to know which Centos repositories various packages are available at.  Is there a directory somewhere?  I tried googling it and didn't find anything.

Comment: see also http://serverfault.com/questions/62026/how-to-know-from-which-yum-repository-a-package-has-been-installed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the repositories configured on your server "yum list" will show you which packages come from which repositories (or are already installed) in the third column.

```
[root@cobbler ~]# yum list | egrep 'foo|cobbler'
cobbler.x86_64                             1.6.6-1.el5                 installed
foomatic.x86_64                            3.0.2-38.3.el5              base
revisor-cobbler.noarch                     2.0.5.2-3.el5               epel
```

Comment: Thanks! I should clarify - I have most repositories disabled... will this still search through them?

Comment: No, but you can pass the "--enablerepo=*" argument and it will.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `yum search` on the package name should show the repository from which it would install.

Comment: Thanks! I should clarify - I have most repositories disabled... will this still search through them?

Comment: no - if they're disabled, `yum` is being told *NOT* to search them. Therefore, if you can't find the package you want, you need to enable other repositories.