# Mysql packages skipped [dependency problems]

Tags: centos, mysql, installation

This may look like a repeat question, but I have done my research and still am unable to find a solution to this problem.

**The problem:**

When installing mysql server on my linux box, I receive `Error` notifications during the mysql installation. These errors state there are missing dependencies.

**The installation output:**

```
[root@ded501 mcnations]# sudo yum install mysql80-community-release-el8-1.noarch                                                                                                                                                             .rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Examining mysql80-community-release-el8-1.noarch.rpm: mysql80-community-release-                                                                                                                                                             el8-1.noarch
mysql80-community-release-el8-1.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@ded501 mcnations]# yum repolist enabled | grep "mysql.*-community.*"
mysql-connectors-community/x86_64       MySQL Connectors Community            74
mysql-tools-community/x86_64            MySQL Tools Community                 33
mysql80-community/x86_64                MySQL 8.0 Community Server            81
[root@ded501 mcnations]# sudo yum install mysql-community-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: reflector.westga.edu
 * extras: repos-tx.psychz.net
 * updates: mirror.teklinks.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:8.0.21-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 8.0.21-1.el8 for pack                                                                                                                                                            age: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-client(x86-64) >= 8.0.11 for package:                                                                                                                                                             mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: net-tools for package: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1                                                                                                                                                            .el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtirpc.so.3(TIRPC_0.3.3)(64bit) for package: mysql-c                                                                                                                                                            ommunity-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtirpc.so.3(TIRPC_0.3.0)(64bit) for package: mysql-c                                                                                                                                                            ommunity-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.22)(64bit) for package: mys                                                                                                                                                            ql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtirpc.so.3()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-se                                                                                                                                                            rver-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-se                                                                                                                                                            rver-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community                                                                                                                                                            -server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package net-tools.x86_64 0:2.0-0.25.20131004git.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.60-1.el7_5 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2                                                                                                                                                            .10.1-7.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) for pac                                                                                                                                                            kage: 2:postfix-2.10.1-7.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:8.0.21-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) for package: mys                                                                                                                                                            ql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: my                                                                                                                                                            sql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) for package: mysql-commun                                                                                                                                                            ity-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtirpc.so.3()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-se                                                                                                                                                            rver-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-se                                                                                                                                                            rver-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community                                                                                                                                                            -server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.60-1.el7_5 will be updated
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.65-1.el7 will be an update
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:8.0.21-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) for package: mys                                                                                                                                                            ql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:8.0.21-1.el8 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) for package: mys                                                                                                                                                            ql-community-libs-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) for package: mys                                                                                                                                                            ql-community-libs-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) for package: mysql                                                                                                                                                            -community-libs-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) for package: mysql                                                                                                                                                            -community-libs-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: mysql                                                                                                                                                            -community-libs-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-se                                                                                                                                                            rver-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community                                                                                                                                                            -server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package postfix.x86_64 2:2.10.1-7.el7 will be updated
---> Package postfix.x86_64 2:2.10.1-9.el7 will be an update
Removing mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.65-1.el7 - u due to obsoletes from mysql-commu                                                                                                                                                            nity-libs.x86_64 0:8.0.21-1.el8 - u
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.65-1.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) for pac                                                                                                                                                            kage: 2:postfix-2.10.1-9.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix-2                                                                                                                                                            .10.1-9.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:8.0.21-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) for package: mys                                                                                                                                                            ql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-cl                                                                                                                                                            ient-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libncurses.so.6()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-                                                                                                                                                            client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community                                                                                                                                                            -client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:8.0.21-1.el8 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) for package: mys                                                                                                                                                            ql-community-libs-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:8.0.21-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtirpc.so.3(TIRPC_0.3.3)(64bit) for package: mysql-c                                                                                                                                                            ommunity-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit) for package: mysql-commun                                                                                                                                                            ity-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtirpc.so.3()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-se                                                                                                                                                            rver-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-se                                                                                                                                                            rver-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-community                                                                                                                                                            -server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-9.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Removing: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.60-1.el7_5.x86_64 (@base)
               libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-commun                                                                                                                                                            ity)
              ~libmysqlclient.so.21()(64bit)
           Updated By: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.65-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
               libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.22)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.10.1-9.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Removing: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.60-1.el7_5.x86_64 (@base)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-commun                                                                                                                                                            ity)
               Not found
           Updated By: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.65-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libtinfo.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Requires: libtirpc.so.3(TIRPC_0.3.0)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

I ran the `--skip` command, and it simply repeated the packages from the `error` section.

I attempted the solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125212/packages-skipped-because-of-dependency-problems) by downloading yumutils & removing duplicates, but apparently there are no duplicates.

I attempted the solution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/322911/centos-6-yum-update-packages-skipped-because-of-dependency-problems) in the first answer by Louis, as well as the the second answer by Ed Moxley. No dice for either attempt.

There is nothing in the mysql documentation (that I can see) that addresses this problem. I have been following mysql's installation procedure found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html#yum-repo-installing-mysql).

**Other Solutions:**

The Mysql documentation states you can download individual packages. I attempted to address one of the missing dependencies via `sudo yum install libstdc++.so.6`. This installation failed, and provided the following message:

```
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

         1. You have an upgrade for libstdc++ which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of libstdc++ of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude libstdc++.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of libstdc++ installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of libstdc++ installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).
```

When I tried running `package-cleanup --cleandupes` I was informed there were no duplicates, which is directly contradictory of the above error...

**UPDATE:**

After uninstalling mysql, I reinstalled the mysql centos 7 version. I ran the install commands and reached the same problem. The output can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/GtB1ci6V).

1. I used the following mysql centos 7 version link here:
   https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=484922 (redhat download)
2. I ran `wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm`
3. I ran `sudo rpm -ivh mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm.2`
4. I ran  `sudo yum install -y mysql-server`

The 4th step is when all errors are triggered.

Any help in solving this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using here?

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You somehow installed a package named `mysql80-community-release` intended for RHEL/CentOS 8, but your system is CentOS 7. This package provides the repositories to download MySQL, but it provides packages for RHEL/CentOS 8. This won't work on your system.

You need to remove this package and replace it with its equivalent for CentOS 7, i.e. with `yum remove mysql80-community-release`. After doing so you need to clear yum's cache with `yum clean all`, then you can install the correct release package and try the installation again.

Alternately, you can upgrade to CentOS 8, and then the installation of packages for CentOS 8 will work.

Answer (score 3):

I tried doing the `yum remove mysql80-community-release` and `yum clean all`, i still had the same issue with the package dependencies. I had to do a `yum clean all --verbose` and it showed me there were cached directories listed under 'untracked repos':

```
Disk usage under /var/cache/yum/*/* after cleanup:
0      enabled repos
7.9 M  disabled repos:
  4.8 M  /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/myorg-elastic-6.x
  3.2 M  /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/myorg-elastic-7.x
5.3 M  untracked repos:
  3.9 M  /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/myorg-puppet5
  700 k  /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/mysql80-community
  376 k  /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/mysql-connectors-community
  340 k  /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/mysql-tools-community
4.0 k  other data:
  4.0 k  /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts
13 M   total
```

I manually removed the /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/mysql* folders and then tried the `sudo yum install -y mysql-server` and that did the trick.